# How do I hide Pylint 1.2.1 error output when using Django?

Tags: python, django, pylint

I am attempting to integrate pylint into our local project that uses Django (1.6.1), and I had it working with Pylint 0.27.0, but now that I've updated to the latest 1.2.1 some new errors are popping up and I can't seem to get them to go away.

Here's the nature of the error:

---

```
from django.db import models

class UserData(models.Model):
    # data...
    fieldA  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fieldB  = models.IntegerField(default=0)

# ...

x = UserData(fieldA=1, fieldB=2)
# The above line of code generates errors:
# Unexpected keyword argument 'fieldA' in constructor call (unexpected-keyword-arg)
# Unexpected keyword argument 'fieldB' in constructor call (unexpected-keyword-arg)
# No value for argument 'name' in constructor call (no-value-for-parameter)
# No value for argument 'bases' in constructor call (no-value-for-parameter)
# No value for argument 'attrs' in constructor call (no-value-for-parameter)
```

---

I've tried getting around this by editing the file during pylint checking, using something like this:

```
UserData.__init__ = lambda self, *args, **kwargs: None
```

But Pylint still prints out the same errors. I also tried directly adding the constructor call to the UserData object, but still no luck.

Is there any way I can modify the code or the pylint settings to quiet these errors? Preferably without hiding those errors for the entire project.

Comment: Update: Currently I'm able to avoid the error messages by running a script that changes my file before running pylint. But this seems like more work than should be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from `pylint` version 1.4, these errors are no longer generated for Django.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable these errors at a module-level by [appending a specific rule](http://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-message-for-a-particular-module-only) in a comment at the top of the module:

```
# pylint: disable=unexpected-keyword-arg, no-value-for-parameter

from django.db import models

class UserData(models.Model):
    ...
```

The symbolic names for the errors (as opposed to the error numbers) can be used [starting with version 0.25.3](http://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#do-i-have-to-remember-all-these-numbers).

---

It appears that this particular issue with pylint is due to [a commit from April 2014](https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/commits/164ac2f#Lcheckers/typecheck.pyT99). The issue has been pointed out by a reviewer, and there are [other users](https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issue/222/having-trouble-linting-schematics-models) that are being affected by this as well, but it doesn't appear to be fixed yet.

Essentially, when pylint analyzes a callable invocation, it checks different parameters based on the type of the callable. Unfortunately, if the callable is a class, then it first checks for `__new__` (which, in some cases, can be present in parent metaclasses) and, if found, completely ignores `__init__`. That is why the errors you are receiving mention `name`, `bases`, `attrs`, e.g. they're the arguments to `__new__`.

Comment: It looks like putting this in the UserData file will work when using the UserData in the same file, but not if the UserData is imported and used in another file. 

(Thanks for posting, I didn't realize you can use the error names instead of looking up error codes now!)

Comment: @camomilk: As another possible option, perhaps you could experiment with using the [`pylint_django`](https://github.com/landscapeio/pylint-django) plugin, which purportedly fixes certain warnings that are generated due to the way in which Django dynamically generates some object attributes (although, I couldn't find any specific mention of the errors you're receiving).

Comment: I tried out pylint_django, but it didn't address this error. I'm guessing it was made for an earlier version of pylint, I think this error is new in pylint 1.2.1 (at least for constructors).

Comment: @camomilk: I believe you are right - I've made an edit with some more information that I found. It appears it's a known bug in pylint.